# how to directly read/write usb (disk) like winhex?

Tags: c++, winapi

My goal is to read /write usb.

First Must open and read usb low -level like 'program'

I used visual c++ with winAPI

below is my test code

```
char path[64];
sprintf(path,"\\\\.\\%c:",volume);//

/////MOST case, user's input is F or G ......
HANDLE usb;

usb=CreateFile(TEXT(path),
               GENERIC_ALL,//
               0,
               NULL,
               OPEN_EXISTING,
               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, //serail I/O
               NULL);

if(usb==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) cout<<"fail to createfile()"<<endl;

cout<<usb<<endl;    

char buf[128];

DWORD dwBytesRead=0;

ReadFile(usb,buf,sizeof(buf),&dwBytesRead,NULL);
cout<<buf<<endl;
cout<<GetLastError()<<endl;

CloseHandle(usb);
```

I wonder CreateFile was correct And ReadFile

GetLastError() of ReadFile() was 87 that means Invalid Input...

what is the wrong??

I referenced MSDN many times...But any page doesn't solve this problem....

What Should I know? fix it?

Comment: You should only call `GetLastError` if you already know that something went wrong (check the return value from `ReadFile`). Successful operations don't necessarily change the last error.

Comment: after I saw your comment, tried to do.
But Only ReadFile 's GetLastError returns 87.....
What's Wrong??

Comment: Did you make sure that you only call `GetLastError()` if `ReadFile` returns `FALSE`?

Comment: Yes Only ReadFile Return 87
when I call CreateFile , GetLastError returned 0

Comment: The `TEXT` macro is for string _literals_. Since it compiles I suspect you don't have unicode selected (otherwise `TEXT(path)` would expand to `Lpath` and that would not exist); you really should. In fact I believe the special prefixes like `\\.\ ` only work in the wide interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I made myself clear enough. You should *only* call `GetLastError` if `ReadFile` *returns* `FALSE`. If `ReadFile` returns `TRUE`, the value returned from `GetLastError` is useless. You *don't* use `GetLastError` to check for errors - you only use it when you *already know* that there's been an error and want to see what it was.

Comment: I've already checked createfile readfile both                                 olny getlasterror of readfile show me error also  readfile returned false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of buffer must be equal to N * (sector size of drive) where N is DWORD value. Sector size can be received with DeviceIoControl(Handle, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, ..., DISK_GEOMETRY, ...).